# Qt 5.1 for OSX installation only includes clang_64 directory, how do I compile with macports gcc?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, c++11, qt-creator

I want to use macports gcc 4.9 with Qt/Qt creator on OSX. The problem is that the 5.1 installation only has a clang_64 directory and no obvious gcc directory. If I set the compiler to gcc 4.9 under preferences/build & run and point Qt to use the qmake under the clang_64 directory, it automatically calls clang++ instead of the gcc executable I specified.

I'm using macports gcc instead of clang because clang requires the system libc++ to be updated and support c++11 features to use them. I'm running OSX 10.6, so from what I understand this is a no go as far as c++11 clang is concerned.

Comment: I don't think gcc and Cocoa will get along anymore.

Comment: Do they need to? I know I've rigged macports gcc to work with earlier versions of Qt in emacs using makefiles. I'm new to the qt creator setup though.

Comment: I think mkspec isn't being selected correctly for gcc. Anyway, AFAIK, clang is the new official compiler for Mac OS.

Comment: Why was this deleted? gcc / clang++ aren't entirely interchangable yet, I would think there are other people out there using gcc on osx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out one way to do it, although it is kind of hacky (Qt creator effectively ignores its own compiler settings). Use the Qt 5.1 qmake (doesn't matter that it's in the clang_64 directory). In the .pro file, add:

```
QMAKE_CC = gcc-mp-4.9
QMAKE_CXX = g++-mp-4.9
QMAKE_LINK = g++-mp-4.9
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

Seems to do the trick. Please comment if there's a problem with this solution / a better solution.

Comment: this seems to be the solution, thank you! I have looked over a lot of threads and not found anything towards this. Also, qmake will use the correct compiler this way